# Meaning of do not thaw for frozen food

Tags: freezing, cooking-time

Today I bought frozen food for the first time and the brand is Mc Coin.

I read the instructions, which have the following instructions;

> Do Not Thaw and cook from frozen

I am unsure how to parse this. Can someone please tell me what the company is telling me in the instructions, and how I am to cook it?

- Should I put my opened packet into freezer  ?
- Should I cook it directly from the packet ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is slightly confusing but I'll try to answer your question.

As far as I can tell McCoin brand is bags of frozen vegetables (correct me if I am wrong).
If it says do not thaw and to cook from frozen, it just means you do not need to thaw it before you cook it.

Thawing is the act of unfreezing something. This can be accomplished by leaving something out at room temperature to naturally thaw.

So if you have frozen corn and want to put it in chili or soup, just throw the frozen corn directly in without thawing it.

Comment: It a kind of a patty of burger but not vegetables so should i keep it in a freez before cooking ?

Comment: From the comment above you said it is a open package. I recommend you actually putting the package in a freezer ziplock bag to prevent freezer burn (esp since its meat).

Comment: ya its a open packet , anyways i keep that think in mind thanks :)

Comment: Many stir-fried veggies will get soggy and 'flaccid' if thawed; fry on high heat and they will turn out (...somewhat...) similar to fresh. Also, fries fried in deep oil straight from freeze will turn much crispier on the surface (although hot oil splatter may be worse.)

Answer (score 9):

If you're cooking store-bought frozen food (a pot pie for instance) and you thaw it first, following the cooking instructions on the package will lead to over-cooking, burnt crust, and a dry meal. The instructions are predicated on direct from freezer to oven and you must adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

It means that the product is meant to go directly from the freezer into the oven / onto the pan.

For some types of food, thawing first, then cooking it in the oven, will lead to a not so crispy product - due to the moisture from the thawing.

Comment: ok so right now my packet is in freezer and its open so should i keep it like that till i cook it ?

Comment: Yes. Just keep it in the freezer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel `Do Not Thaw and cook from frozen` is well particularly well worded.

`Do not thaw prior to cooking` would be better.

Leaving some foods such as meat to defrost out on the bench will see their outside reach temperatures conducive to bacteria growth while the middle is still defrosting.

Hence it can be safer to go straight from the freezer to the frypan.

Also cooking times can be more accurately stated as freezers have a tighter temperature range than room temperatures.

Comment: I guess the wording is probably reading `do not thaw` and `cook from frozen`. I.e. two separate sentences. The wording in the question had me confused as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have to follow the instructions on the package. When it's written- do not thaw, then we have to cook (according to the instructions on the package- fry, oven or whatever is written on the package) straight from freezer into oven or fry it (whatever process is written) and put the remaining amount of material which we haven't used back into the freezer by closing it tightly so that ice doesn't form on the things inside the package.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is answering the question in any way that is substantially different from the answers already given years ago. Can you edit your answer to make it more helpful?